# VBA iterate through columns and apply a formula if it matches (or doesn't matches)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a dynamic spreadsheet (template), which will be used to fetch data frequently. In this dataset I have to correct the  fetched data with slope/intercept values. However, ***I would like to not have any calculations performed if the data is either 0 or Null***. This could also be referrenced through a setpoint in a different column, lets say Sheet1 Column H, with a value of 10.

The K cells in Sheet "*Tags*" contain the slope & intercept values, column G of "*Sheet1*" contains data pulled from a server. For simplicity, lets make them all have 10.0 as a value. However, the data in column G may vary due to process conditions.

Currently I am going through the columns with data and once it matches, it will apply a multiplication or addition to the original values in a certain range as such:

```
' Declare vars
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim Number As Integer
Dim fndStr As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

' Init vars
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
LineText = ""
Number = 0
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through colums till fndStr is found
Do While Not fndStr = "lastWord"
    fndStr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(0, Number)
    Select Case fndStr
    Case Var1:
        Sheets("Tags").Range("K7").Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & FirstRow & ":G" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
        Sheets("Tags").Range("K6").Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & FirstRow & ":G" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
        Number = Number + 1
    Case "lastWord": Exit Do
    Case Else: Number = Number + 1
    End Select
Loop
```

Some additional info, when new data is pulled, the previous, or already existing data, won't be recalculated for these are the FirstRow and LastRow variables meant to which data is appended.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be missing a `Select Case`? Apart from that, what is your question exactly? How to check if a cell content is `0` or `"null"`?

Comment: Thanks for noticing the missing select statement. My question is when I go through the data in that column, how can I avoid a calculation when a cell or range of cells is `0` or `null`, without losing (significant) processing speed?

Comment: For a single cell just use `If thatcell.Value <> 0 And thatcell.Value <> "Null" Then...`. For a range I would replace `"Null"` with 0 beforehand and use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum` (check if the sum is > 0)

Comment: Thanks @arcadeprecinct for your reply, this partially is the solution. My values in a given column can vary and become x instead of 0 and vice versa, which is what is preventing me from adapting this solution. Example of data [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/b2ac8825e9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @arcadeprecinct and @tan-stanley I have been able to find a solution that is acceptable for me to work with.
It replicates the original code, but incorporates the looping and the conditional check. However I have done it on the offset column which contains the setpoint data. No calculations are performed on existing values if the setpoint is `0` or `Null`.

```
' Declare vars
Dim Slope As Double
Dim Intercept As Double

Dim Number As Integer

Dim cellValue As Range
Dim dataRange As Range

Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim Number As Integer
Dim fndStr As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

' Init vars
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
fndStr = ""
Number = 0
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through colums till fndStr is found
Do While Not fndStr = "lastWord"
fndStr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(0, Number)
Select Case fndStr
Case Var1:
        Slope = Sheets("Tags").Range("H7").Value
        Intercept = Sheets("Tags").Range("H6").Value
        Set dataRange = Sheets("R1").Range("G" & FirstRow & ":G" & LastRow)

        For Each cellValue In dataRange
        If cellValue.Offset(0, 1).Value <> 0 And cellValue.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "Null" Then
            cellValue.Value = cellValue.Value * Slope + Intercept
        End If
        Next cellValue

        Number = Number + 1
Case "lastWord": Exit Do
Case Else: Number = Number + 1
End Select
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround this, in addition to what @arcadeprecinct commented is to put an input box.

For example, get user to key in notations to ignore (example: 0 x X), any combinations just in case there is x, X or 0. Split user input and insert into an array.

```
 Dim userInput as String
 Dim allInputs as Variant
 userInput= InputBox("Key in notation to ignore.")
 allInputs = Split(Split(Trim(userInput), " ")
```

Adding on to what @arcadeprecinct commented, do a if else based on the array.

```
for i = 1 to lastRow
   for x = 0 to Ubound(allInputs)

     'do a check here

   next x
next i
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If Inputbox is not necessary, then use a IF a <> 0 OR b <> "x" THEN

Comment: am I correct in thinking that this operation is done after the slope/intercept values from the *Tags* sheet are already used for multiplication & addition to the current values? If so, then the value might be higher than 0 (not Null) depending on the intercept value from the specific calibration. If you are missing specifics please let me know. Thanks!